# I haven been a long time no eaten macaroons

Tags: grammar

> I have not eaten macaroons in a long time.
>
> It has been quite a long time since I've eaten macaroons.
>
> I haven been a long time no eaten macaroons.

Which is the colloquial way to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have not eaten macaroons in a long time.

My preferred form.

> It has been quite a long time since I've eaten macaroons.

I would remove the plural from this second one & recast it as

> It has been quite a long time since I ate a macaroon

which would then make it quite OK.

This last one makes no sense at all

> I haven been a long time no eaten macaroons.

Comment: +1 You could also have *I've gone a long time now without having a macaroon*

Comment: As for #2, I'd use a contraction and omit the _quite_, i.e.: _It's been a long time since I've had a macaroon_.

Comment: Or  in teen-speak: *I haven't had a macaroon in, like, forever.*

Comment: "I've not had one for yonks" ;-)

Answer (score 4):

In England you would probably hear:

*'I haven't had macaroons in ages.'* or: *'I've not had macaroons in ages.'*
*'It's been ages since I've had macaroons.'*

Comment: You'd also hear 'for ages' in the first two.